# VB.net split function with substring

Tags: vb.net

I want to read a certain value in a string. each line is a new string and I want to read the 6th integer on each line..

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles browsebtn.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim filename As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim streamreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
        Dim textfile As String = streamreader.ReadToEnd
        Dim splitChar As String = vbNewLine
        Dim day As Integer = textfile.Substring(10, 2)
        Dim strLine() As String = day.Split(splitChar)
        For Each line As String In strLine

            MsgBox(day)

        Next


    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

But it only returns one number. If I set day as a string and not an integer it works perfect, except it reads the whole string, not the two integers that I need. Please help. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The input file looks like this:

```
23728 121010 00004986 00 00  2 21 22 11   447 114  2   382   292   350

23730 121010 00064120 00 00 51 19 21 12  1064 110  2  4500   572  7734
```

I want my output to be:

```
10
10
```

10 comes from "121010"

Comment: show us input(your text file) and desired output? also note use using block

Comment: I added it into my question. Thanks

Comment: So, how do you determine where that "10" begins and ends?  How is that the 6th integer?

Comment: well it is not 6th integer

Comment: Are you saying you want to start reading the number from the sixth digit of that second number on the line?

Comment: I want it to read the 5th and sixth number of the second number on the line. "121010" it must read 10. the last 2.

Comment: @qwr What do you mean?

Comment: you should split by newline then substring eachline. or you can read line byline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advice:

1. always dispose resources (use using  or try catch finally with
   resource.close)
2. never trust user inputs.
3. write codes that can handle enough  undesired situations

Corrections  based on your code:

```
 Try
        Dim text As String = Nothing

        Using streamreader As New System.IO.StreamReader("text.txt")
            text = streamreader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        If IsNothing(text) = False Then
            Dim strLine() As String = text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            For Each line As String In strLine

                If line.Length > 12 Then MsgBox(line.Substring(10, 2))
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'filenotfound case
    End Try
```

Another way:

On cases where line input can be different (but second should be looked value in our case)

Then can use `Regex`

Here is how:

```
Try
    Using streamreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(file)
        Dim line As String
        While streamreader.Peek > 0
            'unreaded line from file
            line = streamreader.ReadLine()
            'split input by non digits
            Dim numberstrs As String() = Regex.Split(line, "\D+")
            'second numbers last two
            If numberstrs.Length > 1 AndAlso numberstrs(1).Length > 2 Then
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", numberstrs(1).Substring(numberstrs(1).Length - 2, 2))
            End If

        End While


    End Using
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

All of that code that you wrote could be done in much fewer lines, like this:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
    MessageBox.Show(line)
Next
```

Like your example, though, that loads the entire file into memory all at once, which could be problematic if it's a large file.  If the size of the file is a concern, it would be better to just read one line at a time, like this:

```
Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(fileName)
Dim line As String = Nothing
Do
    line = streamReader.ReadLine()
    MessageBox.Show(line)
Loop Until line Is Nothing
```

However, the problem still remains, how do you split the line up into its individual values.  If, as it appears in your question, the values are separated by spaces, then you can just use `line.Split` to separate the line into an array of all of its values.  Then to get the last two characters of one of those values, you can just use `String.SubString`, like this:

```
Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(fileName)
Dim line As String = Nothing
Do
    line = streamReader.ReadLine()
    Dim parts() As String = line.Split()
    Dim wholeNumber As String = parts(1)
    Dim lastTwo As String = wholeNumber.SubString(wholeNumber.Length - 2)
    MessageBox.Show(lastTwo)
Loop Until line Is Nothing
```

Comment: The second suggestion works for reading each line. but the line.split does not. I get warnings.."Index was outside the bounds of the array." I changed the 5 to 11 and it shows the first number and then it gives me the warning again when it tries to read the next.

Answer (score 1):

Steven's answer gets you most of the way there but not all the way. It's worth noting that you actually don't want the 6th integer because that could be 1 or 2 or pretty much anything depending on how you slice it. Also, given in your example you say you want to get 10 from 121010, that could be wither the second group of two numbers or the third group of two numbers from that section of the string.

I note that in your example strings you have some double spaces: You need to sort that out for a kickoff otherwise using `String.Split` will give you empty elements in the array. In fact, using `parts(5)` as Steven has used above gives you an empty element thanks to the double space, and that's not what you want anyway. You would want `parts(2)` and then you would need to `SubString` that to get the number you want.

Another, and I think more elegant, way to do it is to use a RegEx to get the number. Let's say you want the second 10 in that string (shown in bold): 12**10**10. If you know that that string will always be 6 characters, will always be the second field in the input line and you always want the third and fourth numbers then this would do you:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.IO

Private Sub ReadFile
    Dim rx As New Regex("^[^\s]+\s{1}\d{2}(\d{2}?)", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)
    Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(fileName)
    Dim line As String = String.Empty

    Do While streamReader.Peek >= 0
        line = streamReader.ReadLine()
        MessageBox.Show(rx.Matches(line)(0).Groups(1).Value)
    Loop 
End Sub
```

I'm not saying that's the only (or most elegant) RegEx but it will work and means you don't have to use SubString and it doesn't care how long the first field is. It also assumes a single space between fields but that can also be changed to suit. So long as you can work out a rule to get to the bit you want, you can RegEx it. Use Expresso (free and very powerful utility) to help you construct a suitable expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this and I get an error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."

Comment: @DylandeStPern you should put range checkings by yourself. Actually, it is the proper way ,especially ,if that input can be different or  will be provided by users.

Comment: The input will always be the same. Its a log file that saves that 121010 as a date. 2012/10/10. It will always be in that format.

Comment: @DylandeStPern yes it might be always working on you. But SO is checked by many ones. I also added such code

Comment: +1 for Steve reminding me that answers should meet general cases ,too